# C-style String not updated with = operator - C++

Tags: c++

So recently I was playing with the concept of creating my own C++ classes that represent generic data (such as strings, numbers and arrays).

And so far my progress on this has been good (as seen here: https://github.com/LapysDev/LapysCPP).

Except one hitch. For the life of me, I can not figure out why the code below faults when it comes to creating a `String` class object with a variable amount of arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

// Make a new C-style string (or stringify a value).
char* stringify(char character) {
    std::string stream = static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&(std::ostringstream() << character)) -> str();
    char* string = new char[stream.size() + 1];

    strcpy(string, stream.c_str());
    return string;
}
template <typename data> char* stringify(data string) { return strdup(std::string(string).c_str()); }

char* globalString = stringify("");

class String {
    public:
        char* value = stringify("");

        String() {}
        template <typename data>
        String(data value) {
            strcat(globalString, value);
            this -> value = stringify(globalString);
            globalString = stringify("");
        }
        template <typename data, typename... argumentsData>
        String(data value, argumentsData... values) {
            strcat(globalString, stringify(value));
            String(values...);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "String [1]: '" << String("Hello, World!").value << '\'' << std::endl;
    // -> String [1]: 'Hello, World!'

    std::cout << "String [3]: '" << String("Hello,", ' ', "World!").value << '\'';
    // -> String [3]: ''

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried everything I can with the code already (and yes, using an `std::string` for the text value is banned). If there's anyone out there that can explain why using multiple arguments faults when using `char*`'s, you're welcome to comment.

To summarize, I need to be able to create a `String` object with a proper `value` property using a variable amount of arguments.

```
// Works fine
String("Hello, World!").value // -> Hello, World!

// Needs fixing
String("Hello,", ' ', "World!").value // -> ...
```

I understand that this may not be platform to ask questions of this nature but a little help would go a long way. Thanks for reading through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`globalString` is `char*` that points to the return value of `stringify("");`.

`stringify("")` returns `strdup(std::string(string).c_str());`. `strdup` returns a dynamically allocated string that has the length of its parameter ( and the same contents) .

Here, `""` only contains `\0` so the C-string returned from `strdup` will only have a length of `1`.

---

You then try to call `strcat(destination, source)` with `globalString` as the destination, but `globalString` isn't big enough to fit the `source`.

`strcat` says:

> The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large
>   enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null
>   character. The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap. The
>   behavior is undefined if either dest or src is not a pointer to a
>   null-terminated byte string.

So both of your test cases are UB. Even the first test that *seems* to work well.

---

`std::string` handles all of this for you. If you somehow aren't allowed to use it for whatever (stupid) reason a professor has given you, then make sure to allocate enough space for `globalString` before calling `strcat` on it, C-strings are tricky beasts.

Comment: I.. think I'm starting to understand that now. Honestly, I'm going re-implement the code using `std::string`'s instead since it handles finicky details as such. But thanks for explaining things through.